# Non-isomorphic equi-geometric models

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

A *geometry* in the sense of Thurston is a pair $(X,G)$ of a connected simply connected manifold and a Lie group acting transitively with compact stabilizers on $X$ (plus some other technical conditions), and a manifold locally modelled on a geometry is called ($(X,G)$-)*geometric*.
Two geometries are said to be *equivalent* if there is a diffeomorphism $\phi$ between the manifolds, and a $\phi$-equivariant isomorphism of the Lie groups.

This definition is given in order to make sense of our geometric intuition of when two spaces "looks the same", and is quite weaker than the classic concept of isometric spaces. For example if we rescale a sphere $S$ by a constant $\lambda$ we get another non-isometric (affine) manifold $S_\lambda$, and the two have indeed the same geometry. In fact taken together with their isometry groups they *are* equivalent geometries.

Though, there appear to be other pairs of geometry representatives which are non-isometric, and even non-affine.

**Question**: Can anyone provide an example of two such representatives, i.e. a pair $(X_i,\operatorname{Isom}(X_i))$ of non-affine Riemannian manifolds which are geometrically equivalent?

I suspect there are no such example whitin the realm of $2$-manifolds, and I'm looking for some examples in the $Nil$ geometry.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the standard sphere is an **affine manifold**? Did you mean that two spheres with rescaled metrics are **affine isomorphic** (i.e. there is a diffeomorphism preserving their affine connections)?

Comment: I suggest taking $Sol_3$ group and putting different left-invariant Riemannian metrics on it. I am quite sure that with few exceptions, the resulting metrics will have different Levi-Civita connections (but I would not want to do such a calculation, it's too painful).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean that there is a function that multiply the metric tensor at each point by the same constant, I might have used a wrong terminology, please correct me :)

Comment: @MoisheKohan that's actually a good suggestion! I was wondering is it trivial that **any** left invariant metric give rise to a geometry?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Comment: Can you give me a hint of the proof? I wouldn't know better than going along Thurston classification and check that both metrics satisfy the conditions that match the Sol geometry...

Comment: You do not need the classification, just verification of Thurston's axioms. The key thing to verify that regardless of which left-invariant metric you take, the stabilizer of a point in the isometry group will be finite. (At most $Z_2\times Z_2$.)

Comment: Right... then an equivalence of the two geometries can be given with the identity map from the two groups i guess, but i'd need to prove that the isometry groups are in fact isomorphic and the identity is equivariant, shouldn't I?